# Ember navigate to route without redrawing html

Tags: ember.js, masonry

Is it possible to cache the final html client-side so that navigating *back* to a route doesn't redraw the content?

The content is drawn using a model (which is *not* reloaded the second time) and one of the helpers ([`ember-masonry-grid`](https://github.com/gmurphey/ember-masonry-grid)) re-orders the content using jquery.

Once this is done, I would like to keep the html as it was drawn the first time. But it is redrawn every time I visit, adding another second.

If I would do everything manually, I would detach the content element from the DOM without destroying it when I move away, and re-attach it when I move back, which is instant.

Comment: Manipulating the DOM directly is a bit of an anti-pattern for Ember.  Furthermore, there are many ways you could do this, hence your question has close votes as "too broad".  Maybe there is a Masonry solution, but I'm not familiar with that framework.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. _"Furthermore, there are many ways you could do this"_ - I can't think of one. But I do understand that I should not want this. I am still curious about the many ways though. Nothing is more tempting than the knowledge of how to do something that shouldn't be done.

Comment: You really should not postprocess your output with `jQuery` if you care about performance. Get rid of that and try to boot with the current ember beta. Maybe glimmer will give you the speed boost you need. Also consider to use [SAM](http://runspired.github.io/smoke-and-mirrors/) if you render long tables. To answer your question, no, its not possible. To do something like that you would have to hook into glimmer itself.